# Using a packed .obb file inside an android asset folder

Tags: java, android, assets, apk-expansion-files

OBB file packe with the JOBB tool provided by android skd. This is supposed to be used as an expansion file but I do it to secure my asset files.
I added the zip_file project as a library. The obb file contains a collection of .ogg files. I'm trying to play it with mediaplayer with no success. The code compiles without  errors but it doesn't work.

```
public void obbfilemaker() throws IOException{
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile( "file:///android_asset/blob.obb" );
FileInputStream iss = (FileInputStream) expansionFile.getInputStream("rust/my_old_man.ogg");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(iss.getFD());
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

}